# Error in "Hello World" when compiling on Dr. Java?

Tags: java, drjava

I am learning Java, and am testing a simple 'Hello World' program given to me by my teacher. I am using Dr. Java on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Code is below:

```
public class Hello_World
{
    public void go()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I hit the F5 key, and the code compiles. After that, I enter the lines below:

```
greet = new Hello_World();
greet.go();
```

The output is supposed to be 
`Hello, World!`,
 but I am getting `Static Error: Undefined name 'greet'` instead. What am I doing wrong?

Please forgive me if I this is an easy fix (it probably is). I searched SE, but did not find anything that helped.

Comment: Would downvoters be willing to explain their reasons for downvotes? I am not interested in arguing, but would like to be a better part of the SE community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the code:

```
Hello_World greet = new Hello_World();
greet.go();
```

in a main method, which is the point of execution of a java program.  http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html

Comment: Just to be clear, this answer was chosen for the sake of simplicity. Other answers were more complex, which is a severe handicap in the Hello World context.

Answer (score 2):

it should be:

```
Hello_World greet = new Hello_World();
greet.go();
```

The class you defined is called Hello_Word not Hello.

**EDIT**

Your complete code should look something like:

```
public class Hello_World
{
    public void go()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }


public static void main(String[] args){
   Hello_World greet = new Hello_World();
   greet.go();
 }

}
```

Comment: My mistake- I actually entered `Hello_World`, but I copy-pasted the `Hello()` in by mistake. Will edit to reflect this.

Comment: @Qu0rk In that case please post your complete code. So we can pinpoint what is the mistake.

Comment: @Qu0rk Your code lacks main() method which is the entry point of the program. Try the code I proposed, let me know if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Qu0rk Your code had two issues 1- you didn't define the type of variable greet(by writing only greet instead of Hello_World greet) 2- Your class lacked main() method.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your class

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  Hello_World greet=new Hello_World();
  greet.go();
}
```

Since you are running application on your console, you need to have a `main()` method

Comment: dear down voter, the asker has edited the code later. so you must check it before down voting :(
even the commentors on the question have said the same thing.

Comment: or atleast you should tell why it has been down voted so that further answers can be improved.